# Detect Chrome phased rollouts

Tags: google-chrome, rollout

How can phased rollouts be debugged in Chrome?
Is there a screen which shows "you are in rollout group A" or B ?

Same #Chrome Version 70.0.3538.102 (Official Build) (64-Bit)
 version, for me the cert does not work (first screenshot), for my colleague it still does (second screenshot).

The About Screen shows the same version.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is (intentionally) difficult.

Since you know exactly what feature is causing trouble, you can force it with either `--enable-features=LegacySymantecPKI` or `--disable-features=LegacySymantecPKI`.

If you want to roll the dice, that's `--reset-variation-state`, and you can view the current variations at `chrome://version`. Since the variation state only has 13 bits of entropy<sup>[1](https://www.google.com/chrome/privacy/whitepaper.html#variations)</sup>, there will be a large overlap in which variations are toggled together, so you'll have a hard time determining which hashed feature in this list corresponds to `LegacySymantecPKI`, `Disabled`, and `Enabled`.

There's a feature request to show the unhashed field trial names: https://crbug.com/653634.

There's a design doc for the hashing here: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/components/variations/variations_murmur_hash.h